Set up notifications for Root Tenant Group assigments
Set up notifications for Root Tenant Group assigments
azurerm_role_management_policy
I am trying to enable notification(email to slack channel) whenever someone requests for PIM role activiation. The slack channel contains the admins who can approve the request.
I am unable to fix this.
Here is the tf configs:
resource "azurerm_role_management_policy" "tenant_root_mgmt_grp_owner_role_mgmt_pol" {
  

  scope              = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/${var.mg_id}"
  role_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/${var.roles["Owner"].id}"

  eligible_assignment_rules {
    expiration_required = false
  }

  active_assignment_rules {
    expiration_required   = false
    require_justification = false
  }

  activation_rules {
    maximum_duration                   = "PT8H"
    require_multifactor_authentication = true
    require_justification              = true
    require_ticket_info                = true
    require_approval                   = true
    approval_stage {
      primary_approver {
        object_id = var.groups["ad.azure.admins"].id
        type      = "Group"
      }
    }
  }
  notification_rules {
    # Purpose: Sends notifications when users request to activate their eligible roles # When: Triggers on every PIM activation request    
    eligible_activations {
      # Notifies the person requesting activation
      assignee_notifications {
        notification_level    = "All"
        default_recipients    = true  # Include the requestor
        additional_recipients = [var.pim_slack_email]  # Also notify Slack channel
      }

      # Notifies the approvers who need to action the request      
      # approver_notifications {
      #   notification_level    = "Critical"
      #   default_recipients    = true  # Include configured approvers
      #   additional_recipients = [var.pim_slack_email]  # Also notify Slack channel
      # }

      admin_notifications {
        notification_level    = "Critical"
        default_recipients    = false  # Skip default admin notifications
        additional_recipients = [var.pim_slack_email]  # Only notify Slack channel
      }
    }

    # Purpose: Notifies when users are made eligible for roles
    # When: Triggers when PIM eligible roles are assigned
    eligible_assignments {
      admin_notifications {
        notification_level    = "Critical"
        default_recipients    = false  # Skip default admin notifications
        additional_recipients = [var.pim_slack_email]  # Only notify Slack channel
      }
    }

    # Purpose: Notifies when permanent role assignments are made    # When: Triggers for direct (non-PIM) role assignments
    active_assignments {
      admin_notifications {
        notification_level    = "Critical"
        default_recipients    = false  # Skip default admin notifications
        additional_recipients = [var.pim_slack_email]  # Only notify Slack channel
      }
    }
}
}

Please advise how to enable the config ?
I am expecting this config should enable slack email when a user requests for PIM approval.

the snippet shared is configured in the correct way ..check and confrim two things var.pim_slack_email is a valid email address &
The scope and role definition ID are correctly set for the policy

pim_slack_email has a slack channel email address.
Currently the "azurerm_role_management_policy" "tenant_root_mgmt_grp_owner_role_mgmt_pol" and the config were alreadys et up, I have just introduced the notification part.
I can confirm following are correct. I am thinking if it could be due to slack email instead of a usual email, could it be ?
scope              = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/${var.mg_id}"
role_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/${var.roles["Owner"].id}"

If you're using usual mail can you please confirm the integration between usual mail and slack mail @kaushikray is this integration done?


Set up notifications for Root Tenant Group assigments

While configuring Azure Role Management Policy to enable PIM role activation notifications sent to a Slack email channel follow the mentioned steps below

Check the email mentioned should be properly set up in slack to verify the email. If this fails it results in blocker

Eligible_activations and Eligible_assignments blocks should be as per the correct Azure policy structure in Terraforms azurerm_role_management_policy.


Once you confirm the above two-point check with the group info provided is functional and available under the IntraID.
Demo configuration:
resource "azurerm_role_management_policy" "tenant_root_mgmt_grp_owner_role_mgmt_pol" {
  scope              = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/${var.mg_id}"
  role_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/${var.roles["Owner"].id}"

  eligible_assignment_rules {
    expiration_required = false
  }

  active_assignment_rules {
    expiration_required   = false
    require_justification = false
  }

  activation_rules {
    maximum_duration                   = "PT8H"
    require_multifactor_authentication = true
    require_justification              = true
    require_ticket_info                = true
    require_approval                   = true

    approval_stage {
      primary_approver {
        object_id = var.groups["ad.azure.admins"].id
        type      = "Group"
      }
    }
  }

  notification_rules {
    eligible_activations {
      assignee_notifications {
        notification_level    = "All"
        default_recipients    = true
        additional_recipients = [var.pim_slack_email]
      }

      admin_notifications {
        notification_level    = "Critical"
        default_recipients    = false
        additional_recipients = [var.pim_slack_email]
      }
    }

    eligible_assignments {
      admin_notifications {
        notification_level    = "Critical"
        default_recipients    = false
        additional_recipients = [var.pim_slack_email]
      }
    }

    active_assignments {
      admin_notifications {
        notification_level    = "Critical"
        default_recipients    = false
        additional_recipients = [var.pim_slack_email]
      }
    }
  }
}

Refer:
Integration between slack and email:
https://clearfeed.ai/blogs/a-short-guide-to-integrating-slack-with-email
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_management_policy
